# How to get token via header not url

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have a node server, for token auth I use this:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var SEED = require('../config/config').SEED;



// =====================================
//  Verificar token
// =====================================
exports.verificaToken = function(req, res, next) {

    var token = req.query.token;

    jwt.verify(token, SEED, (err, decoded) => {

        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                ok: false,
                mensaje: 'Token incorrecto',
                errors: err
            });
        }

        req.usuario = decoded.usuario;

        next();

    });

};
```

I want to know how can I get the token via header and not URL, now I have to localhost:300/usuario?TOKEN, but I don't know how send and verify token via header, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getToken = function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
    return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
    return req.query.token;
  }
  return null;
}
```

[source](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)

Comment: I would like only accept token on headers, not from url